# How to change column with numbers to column reflecting change in relation to previous row column value grouping by another column value?

Tags: python, pandas

Well, the title's probably very confusing but I tried my best. I'll simplify here with the respective context. I'm making a project for college where I use Python and Scikit-learn to try and predict COVID-19 cases when given the Google's Community Reports' info with Machine Learning. I'm at the stage of pre-processing my data and want to do some changes to the parsed data from the CSV file before advancing. The data's table is the following:

```
iso,country,date,grocery_pharmacy,parks,residential,retail_recreation,transit_stations,workplaces,total_cases,fatalities
```

First, I started by dropping the column *fatalities* since I only want to study the evolution of the total cases. But now I wanted to turn the *total_cases* column from the number of cases to a percentage difference in relation to the previous day in each country. I've tried a lot of stuff, and I came close to my solution, but something was always a little off.

In other words, instead of having the number of cases I wanted to have the increase in percentage in relation to the previous row/day for each country (or if the rows have successive days, it well end up being the same thing).

Thanks in advance and, once again, sorry if my explanation is confusing. I found it kind of hard to make it clear and simple.

Here's an example of how data is on the CSV file:

```
iso ,country        ,date       ,grocery_pharmacy ,parks   ,residential ,retail_recreation ,transit_stations ,workplaces ,total_cases ,fatalities
AR  ,Argentina      ,2020-02-23 ,8.185            ,17.563  ,0.437       ,13.644            ,5.334            ,-2.486     ,0           ,0
AR  ,Argentina      ,2020-02-24 ,-15.875          ,25.605  ,6.321       ,-9.973            ,-26.785          ,-53.687    ,0           ,0
AR  ,Argentina      ,2020-02-25 ,-17.135          ,1.325   ,6.895       ,-19.717           ,-28.485          ,-50.053    ,0           ,0
AR  ,Argentina      ,2020-02-26 ,2.304            ,5.399   ,-2.273      ,0.845             ,9.461            ,12.584     ,0           ,0
AR  ,Argentina      ,2020-02-27 ,-0.404           ,-5.267  ,-0.493      ,-0.584            ,7.983            ,12.407     ,0           ,0
AR  ,Argentina      ,2020-02-28 ,2.075            ,-7.859  ,-0.577      ,2.877             ,7.973            ,12.857     ,0           ,0
AR  ,Argentina      ,2020-02-29 ,4.685            ,-7.582  ,1.409       ,5.265             ,5.595            ,2.156      ,0           ,0
AR  ,Argentina      ,2020-03-01 ,2.873            ,-10.518 ,2.417       ,-2.509            ,0.944            ,-2.36      ,0           ,0
AR  ,Argentina      ,2020-03-02 ,3.958            ,-8.264  ,-1.363      ,0.537             ,6.931            ,16.164     ,0           ,0
AR  ,Argentina      ,2020-03-03 ,5.09             ,-6.241  ,-1.33       ,0.2               ,8.202            ,16.192     ,1           ,0
AR  ,Argentina      ,2020-03-04 ,2.898            ,-0.579  ,-1.916      ,-0.983            ,7.567            ,17.953     ,1           ,0
AR  ,Argentina      ,2020-03-05 ,4.236            ,-8.884  ,-1.491      ,0.735             ,10.191           ,17.557     ,1           ,0
AR  ,Argentina      ,2020-03-06 ,7.63             ,-6.797  ,-1.996      ,6.376             ,12.04            ,18.163     ,2           ,0
AR  ,Argentina      ,2020-03-07 ,7.222            ,-9.604  ,1.219       ,5.391             ,8.476            ,2.756      ,8           ,0
AR  ,Argentina      ,2020-03-08 ,4.425            ,-12.354 ,2.186       ,3.013             ,2.63             ,-2.325     ,12          ,1
AR  ,Argentina      ,2020-03-09 ,5.438            ,-9.125  ,-0.813      ,1.373             ,13.178           ,14.688     ,12          ,1
AR  ,Argentina      ,2020-03-10 ,8.046            ,-8.646  ,-2.092      ,2.687             ,13.621           ,18.222     ,17          ,1
AR  ,Argentina      ,2020-03-11 ,-6.831           ,-24.127 ,0.207       ,-15.515           ,-6.097           ,15.189     ,19          ,1
AR  ,Argentina      ,2020-03-12 ,8.224            ,-15.55  ,-1.41       ,-4.239            ,10.392           ,18.187     ,19          ,1
AR  ,Argentina      ,2020-03-13 ,10.128           ,-17.125 ,-1.125      ,-4.731            ,7.288            ,18.21      ,31          ,2
AR  ,Argentina      ,2020-03-14 ,4.578            ,-40.463 ,7.188       ,-18.762           ,-19.48           ,-3.851     ,34          ,2
AR  ,Argentina      ,2020-03-15 ,16.951           ,-43.747 ,8.781       ,-29.345           ,-17.249          ,-9.812     ,45          ,2
AR  ,Argentina      ,2020-03-16 ,7.879            ,-39.431 ,6.346       ,-26.9             ,-16.545          ,0.894      ,56          ,2
AR  ,Argentina      ,2020-03-17 ,-11.396          ,-53.747 ,10.637      ,-40.83            ,-31.844          ,-11.995    ,68          ,2
AR  ,Argentina      ,2020-03-18 ,-10.624          ,-48.792 ,12.005      ,-42.791           ,-34.599          ,-18.855    ,79          ,2
AR  ,Argentina      ,2020-03-19 ,4.992            ,-54.943 ,12.607      ,-42.199           ,-35.079          ,-24.291    ,97          ,3
AR  ,Argentina      ,2020-03-20 ,-40.436          ,-80.027 ,29.367      ,-78.483           ,-72.116          ,-60.537    ,128         ,3
(...)
AR  ,Argentina      ,2020-03-29 ,-60.955          ,-89.15  ,27.369      ,-86.48            ,-80.396          ,-57.303    ,745         ,19
AR  ,Argentina      ,2020-03-30 ,-51.498          ,-83.033 ,28.489      ,-81.158           ,-77.265          ,-68.314    ,820         ,23
AR  ,Argentina      ,2020-03-31 ,-58.58           ,-85.313 ,29.959      ,-84.535           ,-81.632          ,-76.378    ,1054        ,27
AR  ,Argentina      ,2020-04-01 ,-46.459          ,-79.491 ,27.028      ,-78.877           ,-74.806          ,-64.188    ,1054        ,28
AR  ,Argentina      ,2020-04-02 ,-46.744          ,-81.161 ,28.838      ,-78.947           ,-73.954          ,-64.492    ,1133        ,36
AR  ,Argentina      ,2020-04-03 ,-41.299          ,-78.211 ,30.603      ,-76.75            ,-71.108          ,-62.009    ,1265        ,39
AR  ,Argentina      ,2020-04-04 ,-41.124          ,-81.159 ,27.254      ,-77.294           ,-70.592          ,-53.548    ,1451        ,43
AR  ,Argentina      ,2020-04-05 ,-53.837          ,-86.676 ,25.873      ,-82.974           ,-75.91           ,-52.12     ,1451        ,44
AU  ,Australia      ,2020-02-23 ,4.283            ,8.616   ,-0.263      ,3.354             ,4.062            ,-1.661     ,15          ,0
AU  ,Australia      ,2020-02-24 ,0.807            ,-9.507  ,-1.447      ,-0.815            ,7.875            ,17.275     ,15          ,0
AU  ,Australia      ,2020-02-25 ,-0.769           ,-8.38   ,-1.334      ,-2.52             ,10.086           ,14.661     ,15          ,0
AU  ,Australia      ,2020-02-26 ,-0.263           ,-5.036  ,-1.139      ,-0.574            ,9.637            ,13.935     ,15          ,0
AU  ,Australia      ,2020-02-27 ,1.369            ,-1.533  ,-1.407      ,-0.396            ,10.31            ,14.167     ,15          ,0
AU  ,Australia      ,2020-02-28 ,5.717            ,-0.464  ,-2.66       ,3.968             ,13.725           ,16.627     ,15          ,0
AU  ,Australia      ,2020-02-29 ,6.102            ,17.769  ,-1.014      ,6.399             ,10.955           ,3.993      ,25          ,0
AU  ,Australia      ,2020-03-01 ,7.434            ,19.68   ,-0.488      ,3.706             ,5.534            ,-0.985     ,27          ,1
AU  ,Australia      ,2020-03-02 ,4.658            ,-0.576  ,-0.446      ,-0.487            ,5.854            ,10.245     ,30          ,1
AU  ,Australia      ,2020-03-03 ,7.375            ,-14.005 ,-1.45       ,-1.669            ,9.052            ,15.05      ,39          ,1
AU  ,Australia      ,2020-03-04 ,12.463           ,-15.141 ,-0.693      ,0.35              ,6.519            ,13.897     ,52          ,2
AU  ,Australia      ,2020-03-05 ,9.132            ,-18.612 ,-0.383      ,-2.032            ,6.129            ,13.498     ,55          ,2
AU  ,Australia      ,2020-03-06 ,14.217           ,-6.468  ,-2.163      ,3.224             ,9.36             ,15.623     ,60          ,2
AU  ,Australia      ,2020-03-07 ,12.235           ,9.747   ,-0.082      ,3.457             ,2.708            ,2.357      ,63          ,2
AU  ,Australia      ,2020-03-08 ,8.191            ,13.52   ,-0.155      ,3.144             ,0.48             ,-1.806     ,76          ,3
AU  ,Australia      ,2020-03-09 ,3.112            ,5.013   ,3.989       ,-3.066            ,-9.266           ,-14.363    ,91          ,3
AU  ,Australia      ,2020-03-10 ,8.625            ,-11.428 ,-0.71       ,-2.471            ,6.054            ,13.436     ,107         ,3
AU  ,Australia      ,2020-03-11 ,8.26             ,-1.633  ,-0.673      ,-1.288            ,5.57             ,13.547     ,128         ,3
AU  ,Australia      ,2020-03-12 ,10.845           ,2.169   ,-0.755      ,-1.38             ,5.811            ,13.109     ,128         ,3
AU  ,Australia      ,2020-03-13 ,17.257           ,-8.233  ,-0.811      ,0.648             ,4.779            ,14.473     ,200         ,3
AU  ,Australia      ,2020-03-14 ,19.701           ,-15.375 ,2.207       ,-0.597            ,-10.157          ,3.046      ,250         ,3
AU  ,Australia      ,2020-03-15 ,23.875           ,-7.679  ,2.445       ,-2.029            ,-12.671          ,-1.464     ,297         ,3
AU  ,Australia      ,2020-03-16 ,33.359           ,-17.606 ,1.143       ,-1.461            ,-7.242           ,12.331     ,377         ,3
AU  ,Australia      ,2020-03-17 ,34.723           ,-20.614 ,3.015       ,-5.142            ,-13.586          ,5.292      ,452         ,5
AU  ,Australia      ,2020-03-18 ,31.793           ,-14.65  ,4.703       ,-6.542            ,-18.331          ,1.676      ,568         ,6
AU  ,Australia      ,2020-03-19 ,25.082           ,-8.968  ,5.473       ,-10.245           ,-21.507          ,-0.307     ,681         ,6
AU  ,Australia      ,2020-03-20 ,20.021           ,-12.096 ,5.649       ,-11.558           ,-22.129          ,0.319      ,791         ,7
AU  ,Australia      ,2020-03-21 ,10.704           ,-9.065  ,6.702       ,-16.562           ,-27.716          ,-4.421     ,1071        ,7
AU  ,Australia      ,2020-03-22 ,9.716            ,-10.81  ,6.436       ,-18.342           ,-33.682          ,-11.581    ,1549        ,7
AU  ,Australia      ,2020-03-23 ,17.435           ,-27.17  ,7.885       ,-17.046           ,-35.834          ,-5.813     ,1682        ,7
AU  ,Australia      ,2020-03-24 ,4.095            ,-30.187 ,12.372      ,-30.031           ,-44.736          ,-18.673    ,2044        ,8
AU  ,Australia      ,2020-03-25 ,1.905            ,-32.841 ,14.373      ,-30.942           ,-49.861          ,-22.719    ,2364        ,8
AU  ,Australia      ,2020-03-26 ,1.699            ,-23.22  ,15.915      ,-34.244           ,-52.948          ,-26.989    ,2810        ,13
AU  ,Australia      ,2020-03-27 ,2.206            ,-30.104 ,16.705      ,-35.483           ,-52.921          ,-26.425    ,3143        ,13
AU  ,Australia      ,2020-03-28 ,-8.503           ,-33.523 ,14.773      ,-40.954           ,-53.205          ,-26.807    ,3640        ,14
AU  ,Australia      ,2020-03-29 ,-18.732          ,-34.655 ,13.283      ,-44.894           ,-58.146          ,-32.674    ,3984        ,16
```

Comment: Can you please share the expected output?

Comment: This is a standard pandas question, and it has nothing to do with `scikit-learn` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: To make your question more clear, please include a [mcve] with a sample of your input, your expected output based on that input, and code for what you've tried based on your own research

Comment: @desertnaut it was only because I know scikit-learn has tools for pre-processing like this so maybe it could be done with it. Sorry about that

Comment: No problem; just please keep in mind for the future that this is not the correct practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `groupby` on country and take [`pct_change`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html) of `total_cases` like below:

```
df.groupby('country')['total_cases'].pct_change(fill_method='backfill')
```

You can also handle null values in your column with`fill_method='backfill'`. It will fill `Nan` with previous row's value.

**This will give your percentage change for each country from previous day.**

Sample output:

```
Out[213]: 
22    0.244444
23    0.214286
24    0.161765
25    0.227848
26    0.319588
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use panda's builtin .pct_change().

```
df['pc'] = df['total_cases '].pct_change(periods=1)

print(df.tail(5))

    iso country date    grocery_pharmacy    parks   residential retail_recreation   transit_stations    workplaces  total_cases fatalities  pc
22  AR  Argentina   2020-03-16  7.879   -39.431 6.346   -26.900 -16.545 0.894   56.0    2.0 0.244444
23  AR  Argentina   2020-03-17  -11.396 -53.747 10.637  -40.830 -31.844 -11.995 68.0    2.0 0.214286
24  AR  Argentina   2020-03-18  -10.624 -48.792 12.005  -42.791 -34.599 -18.855 79.0    2.0 0.161765
25  AR  Argentina   2020-03-19  4.992   -54.943 12.607  -42.199 -35.079 -24.291 97.0    3.0 0.227848
26  AR  Argentina   2020-03-20  -40.436 -80.027 29.367  -78.483 NaN NaN NaN NaN 0.000000
```

Comment: Thanks! And how can I make sure the percentage change is only applied when the country is the same?